# Resolve entire TLD to localhost on a Windows device

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, localhost

Is it possible to configure the Windows network stack such that any hostname ending in `.local` (or another TLD if `.local` presents a problem) is resolved to 127.0.0.1?

For background, I'm a web developer who has several active sites under development at a time.  I run a separate locally hosted instance for each and use the hostname to route to the correct instance.  For example, I might have `project1.local`, `project2.local`, and so on.  For this to work, I create entries in my hosts file that point these domains back to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1   project1.local
127.0.0.1   project2.local
127.0.0.1   project3.local
```

I'd like to be able to do this without having to modify my hosts file each time I add or remove projects from my environment.  I'd also prefer to avoid adding new software (ie. installing my own local DNS server) if possible as I'm looking for a simple solution that would be easy to recreate on future work machines.

Comment: Hosts files do not support any kind of wildcards, so a local DNS server is probably the best way to go.  Another option would be to add some custom configuration to your router's DNS server (assuming your router is providing DNS and allows you to add such configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll probably just stick to hosts files, then, since it'll be easier to manage than running a DNS server.

Comment: There are very simple DNS servers like [DNSchef](https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef) which allows to change all DNS requests/responses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `.localhost` as a local TLD on Windows without configuring the `etc/hosts` file and I can browse somedomain.localhost on Chrome and Firefox

I've also noticed that when using `1.1.1.1` as my primary DNS server, pinging to `.localhost` subdomains returns the loopback address